# Obligations implied by the Apache 2.0 License for an open source project

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0

I'm using two libraries under Apache 2.0 license [opennlp](https://github.com/apache/opennlp) and [crux](https://github.com/chimbori/crux). The source code of my Android opensource app will be on Github. And the app will be released on Google Play Store. What are all my obligations to these two libraries? (What to include in my source code on Github and in my app on Play Store). What is obligatory and what is optional?

I'm using in my project [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/license) as well, two times. Once on its own and another time via crux which uses Jsoup as well. Jsoup has MIT license. Is it sufficient for my project to have Apache 2.0 license?

My app will be free and open source.

Comment: Both [Apache](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) and [MIT](https://opensource.org/license/mit/) licenses are easy to read and understand. Please explain in detail which parts of the license language is causing difficulties for you to understand?

Answer (score 3):

Standard Apache 2.0 license requirements apply.
You can read them in many places, but it boils down to:

- do not claim authorship
- show authorship and license text in source code and binary files
- indicate changes

A detailed description can be found on many sites like [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/apache-2.0/).

As for what I suggest you do.

Include in the "About the Application" section (if any) the "Open Source Licenses" section. You can see how this will look on your Android phone in the settings and about the phone in the "Legal information" section. This may vary on different phones.

Google also describes what to do.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource

**This is not legal advice**